# How do we handle unethical questions?

Tags: discussion

I recently [commented on a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389438/how-to-play-a-game-after-being-banned-in-battlefield-1942#comment547398_389438) that I believe to be, unethical. To summarize, the OP is asking what they can do to get around a ban placed on their account in a game they're playing. Subsequently, my current course of action has been to downvote the question, leave my comment, and then come here to determine if any additional steps should be taken. I also edited the question to clean it up a bit and improve readability, just-in-case the question is safe to ask.

My first instinct was to flag the post *rude and abusive*, but it doesn't really fit because the language isn't rude, nor abusive (on the contrary), and the code of conduct doesn't seem to cover this particular situation, so that flag doesn't fit.

My second thought was to flag it *in need of moderator intervention*, but does that really fit? I was hesitant because it may be a bit, over the top for the situation. I was unsure on it, so I wanted to get a second opinion.

---

How do we handle questions that *seem* unethical?

Answer (score 5):

Ban appeals aren't unethical at all. They're a normal part of moderation: punishing people, then allowing them back when they feel remorseful for what they did. How to evade a ban could have "appeal it" as a reasonable answer.

About unethical questions in general: it depends on the question that's being asked. Ethics and morals are different for every user, and something you consider unethical might actually be completely fine for most users. Some games are full of hard choices, some of which are unethical, and it would be difficult to answer questions on what certain unethical choices do if we don't allow unethical questions.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say questions about ban-avoidance are kind of off topic, in both ways I can see the question getting asked.

If the question asked is how to appeal a ban, well thats the kind of question that is quickly answered by 'Contact Customer service, see what happens. We can't do much to help you'.

If the question is how to dodge a ban, such as trying to create a new account without having to buy the game again or escaping a hardware id so you can be played on a banned device, then those are against TOS, and I'm pretty sure questions that are directly against the TOS of the game they are about are considered off topic.